# How to merge multiple LSTM models and to fit them

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to merge two LSTM Sequential models, but without success. I am using the `Concatenate()` method from `tensorflow.keras.layers` . Whenever I try to concatenate the models it says `ValueError: A Concatenate layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs` which doesn't make sense, because the two models are passed in the list.

This is the code that I have for the models:

```
# Initialising the LSTM
regressor = Sequential()

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

lstm_model = Sequential()


lstm_model.add(LSTM(units = 4, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))

# returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 4

# Adding the output layer
lstm_model.add(Dense(units = 1))


merge = Concatenate([regressor, lstm_model])
hidden = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
conc_model = Sequential()
conc_model.add(merge)
conc_model.add(hidden)
conc_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae', 'acc'])

history = conc_model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.1, epochs = 50, batch_size = 32, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
```

How to concatenate and fit those models? I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you get error when you try to fit the model?

Comment: Yes, it seems it is on the fit

Comment: you X_train is single array? you have 2 inputs so what is shape of your X_train

Comment: Yes the X_Train is a single array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is cause by your fit input, it should be a list of two inputs instead of one input, because your `conc_model` require two inputs

Check the [docs of fit function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), it says: **Input data could be a Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs)**

So you need to split the X_train into list of two array, first one for `regressor` second for `lstm_model`

Comment: It fails on the fit

Comment: Can you give an example split of the X_train? I tried with X_train = train_test_split(regressor, lstm_model) and then added just X_train in the fit, but it didn't worked

Comment: That is depends on whats your `X_train` structure and type are, you need to split `X_train` into the `[<array, shape=(batch size, X_train.shape[1], 1)>, <array, shape=(batch size, X_train.shape[1], 1)>]`, if your `X_train` structure and type is common like numpy array or tensor, then you can find function you need easily in the official docs or anywhere online, if it's not then make another question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

you are using Sequential and concatenate together, this is wrong.

you should used Input and Model keyword to define model.

```py
inp_layer1 = Input(shape=(1,))
m1 = Dense(1) (inp_layer1)

inp_layer2 = Input(shape=(1,))
m2 = Dense(1) (inp_layer2)

m3 = concatenate([m1,m2])
model = Model(inputs=[inp_layer1,inp_layer2],outputs=m3)
```

Comment: As far as I know `concatenate` is used on the functional API and cannot be used with `Sequential` and `Concatenate` can be used with `Sequential`

Comment: my code is working but when i concatenate 2 `sequential` model it dont work.

Comment: It doesn't work with `concatenate` it should be working with `Concatenate`